# Exclamation Mark in Backbone Router routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router, backbone-routing

In our project we have a bunch of routes such that the original route: routeAction is followed by !route: routeAction like so..

```
'home': 'homeAction',
'!home': 'homeAction',
```

No one on the team knows why we do this. Anyone here know? Can't find anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding that **exclamation mark** (`!`) has nothing with backbone that's why you can't find anything in the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/) about it Backbone treats it like any usual URL.
 But If the project is a little bit too old I think this was used to [let google crawl that ajax content](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1) this way accessing the route with `!` will stay valid and calls the appropriate handler.